# How can I remove two elements from a list without a loop?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
A = [A, B, #, C]
```

Using `a.remove('#')` I can remove the hashtag, but how can I remove both the hashtag and the element before without a loop considering I don't know what the element before the hashtag is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need to know the index of the hashtag.

```
A = ['A', 'B', '#', 'C']
hashtag_index = A.index('#')
# here I am removing the hashtag
A.pop(hashtag_index)
# here the element before
if hashtag_index != 0:
    A.pop(hashtag_index - 1)

print(A)
# ['A', 'C']
```

You can also use del in one line (doesn't work when index == 0)

```
del A[hashtag_index - 1:hashtag_index+1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `list.index` to find the position of the hashtag and then use two slices to remove the two elements.

```
pos = A.index('#')
A = A[:pos - 1] + A[pos + 1:]
```

`A[:pos - 1]` gives everything up to, and not including, the element before the hashtag. `A[pos + 1:]` gives everything after the hashtag, then you can combine these two into one list

Alternatively refer to @usr2564301's solution in the comments which removes it in-place (without having to reassign A): `A[pos-1:pos+1] = []`, using the same `pos` from above

**Note**: This assumes that the hashtag is not the first element in the list, otherwise unexpected behavior will occur (refer to @sertsedat's comment below)

Comment: index out of range error won't occur. but the result will be `['#', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C']`

Comment: @sertsedat ah you're right, I forgot -1 refers to the last element

Comment: very interesting what headache one small edge case can give us.

Comment: How about `A[pos-1:pos+1] = []`? This modifies the list in-place. (It won't work when `pos=0` but that contradicts OP's requirement "and the element before" anyway.)

Comment: @usr2564301 nice, didn't think about that!

Comment: @usr2564301 yup now OP has more than enough to choose from

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the element is in the list, you can use `index` to get the position in the list and then a couple of `pop` to remove the items (assuming that if the hashtag is the first of the list, you just want to remove that):

```
a= ['A', 'B', '#', 'C']
index = a.index('#')
# if the element is not in the list, you will get a ValueError!
a.pop(index)
if index > 0:
    a.pop(index-1)

print(a)

# output
['A', 'C']
```

If you are not sure that the element is in the list, you should then check first if it is, in order to avoid getting a `ValueError`:

```
a= ['A', 'B', '#', 'C']
if '#' in a:
    index = a.index('#')   
    a.pop(index)
    if index > 0:
        a.pop(index-1)

print(a)

# output
['A', 'C']
```

Answer (score -1):

one way to do it:

```
A = ['A', 'B', '#', 'C']

print(A) #output = ['A', 'B', '#', 'C']

index = A.index("#")
A.pop(index)
A.pop(index-1)

print(A) #output = ['A', 'C']
```